# What should GitHub repo package folder of a Python project include to manage dependencies?

Tags: python, python-packaging, requirements.txt

I have a question that I cannot seem to find the right answer for (perhaps I am articulating it incorrectly).

My program is dependent on Numpy and datetime. should I include those inside the modules folder? Or is it assumed that some of the fundamental packages are already going to be installed on the computer the end user will use?

Layout:

```
PROGRAM_NAME/
-main
-Readme
--/Modules
  -__init__
  -constants
  -program_name
```

Comment: TL;DR: use a [build system](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/). There are many to chose from, some published by the PSF/PPA, some made by third-parties. Using any one will allow users to install all of your packages dependencies automatically just by e.g. `pip install`ing your package.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
You could start by adding a `requirements.txt` to your project, although this is outdated advice if you want to build a package, but will be fine for small projects. If you want to build a package, take a look at this documentation about PEP517: https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/

You can also use other build tools to build packages like https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry

This shell command will export your projects dependencies as a file named requirements.txt:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Once you’ve got your requirements file, you can head over to a different computer or new virtual environment and run the following:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

A requirements file is a list of all of a project’s dependencies. This includes the dependencies needed by the dependencies. It also contains the specific version of each dependency, specified with a double equals sign (==).

Read more here: https://realpython.com/lessons/using-requirement-files/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it IS a pretty simple program, and based on the questions it seems that it will be best practice to have a method that allows an end user to install required packages.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to put dependencies would be in a `requirements.txt` file. Then to install all the requirements, use `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`.

More information on `requirements.txt` can be found [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) in the pip documentation.

Comment: This is outdated advice. These days, packages would use a PEP-517 build system to specify their dependencies.